# How do I affect only some items in my array Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

My Wordpress posts shows images, all images have the .aligncenter class.
I would like the images which are less than 400px to have the `display:inline-block;` style and to reduce their size to 40%.

I tried it this way:

```
var size = jQuery(".aligncenter").width();
if(jQuery( size < 400)) {
jQuery(".aligncenter").css({
 'display' : 'inline-block',
 'width' : '40%'
});
}
```

This script affects all images in the post, not only the ones that are less than 400px. How can I affect only images that are less than 400px?

Comment: This is easy with `filter` but you're trying to solve a CSS problem with Javascript. It's usually a bad idea.

Comment: are you looping all images in same class?

Comment: @mayk yes, all the images have the same class

Comment: Have you tried $(".algincenter").each(function(){ if($(this).width()<400){$(this).css(...) } })

Comment: seems your `if` condition is wrong, it should atleast be like this `if( size < 400) {`

Comment: If it has to be done via javascript / jQuery, mayk's right, it needs to be done via a loop of each item with the chosen class. But I agree with Denys, that's a job for CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".algincenter").each(function(){ if($(this).width()<400){$(this).css(...) } })
```

The code above, takes each image and checks it one by one, think of it as a loop which will run through all the images in your container.  If the loop finds an image which is bigger `<` than 400px it will apply the css styles to that image. If not, it will ignore it.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.